# Policy to Avoid duplicate https calls on an Azure Api endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I have some troubles regarding some duplicate calls on my Azure Api Endpoint. For example, I see that my endpoint :

> tennis/getballs

has been called twice

> First : 2020-11-02T18:07:19.8261667Z

> Second :2020-11-02T18:07:19.881239Z

I want to avoid this second call which has the same payload (like "I don't do this call because it's too close than the first call", it's ok if it's 5 seconds later). I'm looking for something with the Policy but I didn't find something interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Accourding to your description, maybe you want to `add rate limit` to your api. I think [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api#protect-an-api-by-adding-rate-limit-policy-throttling) will help you.

This part describes how to prevent your api being called within short time. You can modify the policy to meet your custom request.

1. Enter api management webpage then select your target API > All operations > Design.
2. In the Inbound processing section, select the code editor (</>) icon.
3. Position the cursor inside the  element and select Show snippets at the top right corner.
4. In the right window, under Access restriction policies, select + Limit call rate per key.
5. Modify your rate-limit-by-key code (in the  element) to the following code:

```
calls="3" renewal-period="15" means you can call this api no more than 3 times within 15 seconds.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxlvY.png)

```
<policies>
   <inbound>
     <rate-limit-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="15" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
     <base />
   </inbound>
   <backend>
     <base />
   </backend>
   <outbound>
     <set-header name="X-Powered-By" exists-action="delete" />
     <set-header name="X-AspNet-Version" exists-action="delete" />
     <redirect-content-urls />
     <base />
   </outbound>
   <on-error>
     <base />
   </on-error>
</policies>
```

After editing, you can call your api then you will find `429 Too many requests` when calling too many times as your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Tinywa for your answer, It can be a solution, you think it's possible to parameterize this constraint if the calls have only the same payload ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And in my opinion, I'm not sure whether the api would return the same response when calling it with the same parameter within a short time. So it's hard to parameterize this constraint. On the other hand, I don't know how to change the policy automatically by Azure. So my suggestion is setting a policy on your opinion first(e.g. 1 time per second) and modify it according to the daily usage.